# бот меняет свое сообщение и после этого сразу выскакивает ошибка. как это исправить?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["work"])
def reg_start (mess: types.Message):
    if mess.text == "/work":
        m = bot.send_message(mess.from_user.id, "Время узнать кем ты будешь работать\n"+random.choice(works))
    for i in range(10):
        sleep(1)
        bot.edit_message_text(text="сообщеие изменено",  chat_id=mess.chat.id, message_id=m.message_id)
```

[image: error photo]

Comment: the code runs without errors, the error occurs at the moment when the bot has changed the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он у тебя меняет сообщение, на то же что и было.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["work"])
def reg_start (mess: types.Message):
    # зачем эта проверка?
    # if mess.text == "/work":
    message_new = bot.send_message(mess.from_user.id, "Время узнать кем ты будешь работать\n"+random.choice(works))
    for i in range(10):
        sleep(1)
        bot.edit_message_text(text=f"сообщение изменено{i}",  chat_id=message_new.chat.id, message_id=message_new.message_id)
```